# How to copy an external image to local?

Tags: php, image-processing, symfony, image-manipulation

I want to retrive an http external image an copy it to a folder on my server (eg. /images/example.jpg)

Is there a way to do this with symfony 2.0 or with basic PHP 5 functions?

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this:

file_put_contents('tmp.jpg', file_get_contents('http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/3603.jpg'));

But, be careful, if it's a web page, it maybe very slow, depending on the speed of image page.

Comment: Also you have to enable the external url opening in your server configuration, so you won't do it on a shared hosting environment.